# Pandas - Row mask and 2d ndarray assignement

Tags: pandas, numpy, mask

Got some problems with pandas, I think I'm not using it properly, and I would need some help to do it right.

So, I got a mask for rows of a dataframe, this mask is a simple list of Boolean values.
I would like to assign a 2D array, to a new or existing column.

```
mask = some_row_mask()
my2darray = some_operation(dataframe.loc[mask, column])
dataframe.loc[mask, new_or_exist_column] = my2darray
# Also tried this
dataframe.loc[mask, new_or_exist_column] = [f for f in my2darray]
```

Example data:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Fun': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'Data': [10, 20, 30]})
mask = dataframe['Fun']=='a'
my2darray = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
column = 'Data'
new_or_exist_column = 'NewData'
```

Expected output

```
  Fun  Data          NewData

0   a    10  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

1   b    20              NaN

2   a    30  [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

dataframe[mask] and my2darray have both the exact same number of rows, but it always end with :

ValueError: Mus have equal len keys and value when setting with ndarray.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT - In context:

I just add some precisions, it was made for filling folds steps by steps: I compute and set some values from sub part of the dataframe.
  Instead of this, according to Parth:

```
dataframe[new_or_exist_column]=pd.Series(my2darray, index=mask[mask==True].index)
```

I changed to this:

```
dataframe.loc[mask, out] = pd.Series([f for f in features], index=mask[mask==True].index)
```

All values already set are overwrite by NaN values otherwise.
  I miss to give some informations about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some example data and expected output?

Comment: I added some example data ! =)

Comment: Do you want first element of my2darray to be assigned to first row of df and 2nd element to be assigned to last row of df? Can you please put expected output if possible?

Comment: Ok, I'm definitely not good at sharing my problems. I added an expected output! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataframe[new_or_exist_column]=np.nan
dataframe[new_or_exist_column]=pd.Series(my2darray, index=mask[mask==True].index)
```

It will give desired output:

```
Fun  Data          NewData
0   a    10  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1   b    20              NaN
2   a    30  [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Also, I see that dataframe[new_or_exist_column]=pd.Series(my2darray, index=mask[mask==True].index) is enough in my case!
You saved my day Parth!

Comment: @RomainCendre Glad to help.Thanks.

Comment: I just add some change on my original post. I miss to give you some informations, but you gave me the main idea! =)